# Firebase app indexing without web content

Tags: firebase, android-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

Is it possible to implement Firebase App Indexing for your app if it does not have any web content.
App is a stand-alone offline app with no online/web content.

I want the search results in "In-apps" tab of Google search, to show the results from my app.

Is it possible ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for Android apps, there is a new feature of [Firebase App Indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/app) that allows you to index content driven by user discovery.  The feature is generally referred to as "[personal content indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/personal-content)".  The idea is that as the user browses content in your app, you record those interactions with Firebase App Indexing.  Then, that content becomes searchable from the Google search box on the device.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this is what I need. will give it a try

Comment: Personal content indexing is intended to be used with the content your user generates - their contacts, recipes, favourited items, etc. If that's your case then ok. But for a general case where you have a bunch of non-personal, non-user-generated app content accessible to the user, you should not use personal content indexing.

Comment: is it still possible? Personal content indexing is working with firebase app indexing 19.1.0  version ?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/personal-content is not available